# How to set variables with return value from PHP script?

Tags: bash

How would I go about setting variables in bash using the return value of a PHP script?

So something like this: `options=php my_script.php`

The script returns anything necessary, at the moment it returns:

options[abc]='one two three'

options[foo]='bar'

etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say "return" you probably mean print to std-out, right? Also, can you show an actual example output?

Comment: If you want the actual *exit code* of a finished process, you can access it with the bash variable `$?`, such as `returnCode=$?`. This variable always represents the exit code of the last process to be invoked by the bash shell (generally the previous command). From what you are describing, you don't want the return value at all, you want to parse the standard output. This is very different than the process' return code.

Comment: I dont know how php can return multiple exit code?  Are you looking for something like putevn of php?  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Comment: I suspect you want to create an associative array (named `options`) in your bash script? You'd get that using an evil `eval`

Comment: @AvalSarri `putenv` will only update the environment variable of a current process, not parent processes or other contexts. In other words, a PHP process that uses `putenv` will not create environment variables accessible from other processes, including bash.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I’m looking for the info on stdout to be parsed. Meaning, the parent process retrieves variable info from child. I’m thinking a for/while loop should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I achieved this using variables. Basically, read in the data to the while loop using `-r` option for `read`. Example below.

```
options=`./command-prompt $choice`
while read -r line
    do
        echo "$line"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$options")
```